# Create titles in MYSQL from h1 tags of post (WordPress)

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, title

I imported a site to Wordpress that has no titles associated to posts. Each post does have h1 tags...

Can anyone tell me the best way to go into MYSQL and write some script to auto generate the titles of each post based on the h1 tags of each???

When final I need to be able to see these titles in the post section of the WordPress dashboard.

Below Is the code based on your responses Andrew. I created a file called createtiles.php and included it in my rrot directory. Not sure whats going on but when i look at my Post section in WordPress dashboard I still see (No Title).

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

$all_posts = mysql_connect("SELECT * FROM wp_posts");

while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_posts))

{ $pid = $item['post_id'];

$new_title = substr($item['post_content'],0,70);

mysql_query("UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title='".$new_title."'");
}
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

(Some of my post only have h1 tags with no other content. )

Comment: Can you post what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Ignore my answer below. I'm rewriting it. I read wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Well, just a quick rough draft without doing much of any of the work for you.

```
$title = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT post_content, post_title, post_id FROM wp_posts");

 foreach($title as $final_title) {
   $post_id = $final_title['post_id'];
   $post_content = $final_title['post_content'];

   $final_content = '<h1>'.$final_title['post_title'].'</h1><br /><br />'.$post_content;

   $q = mysql_query("UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content='".$final_content."'");
 }
```

And that's all she wrote. I didn't do much of the work for you, but it definitely is the way to go. Vote Up.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not pay attention to my other answer. It is backwards to what you want.

You need to use https://www.php.net/substr method to grab a certain amount of characters from your title. I would grab that first 26 letters from your post and then update the titles.

What you need to do is something like this.

```
$all_posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_posts");

while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_posts)) {
      $pid = $item['post_id'];
      $new_title = substr($item['post_content'],0,26);

      mysql_query("UPDATE wp_posts SET post_title='".$new_title."'");
}
```

Now that's all she wrote. ;)

Comment: Thanks, Would i just create a table in MYSQL and add that code??

Comment: Create a PHP file called createtitles.php and then paste this in it.

But you need to take time at php.net's mysql_connect() functionality. 

You need to make you both create, and close a mysql function. This script will do what you need it to do. 

Although, as of now, it's 98% complete and you gotta take the time and help learn the rest for yourself. :) If you need help, I will guide you all the way though.

http://us3.php.net/function.mysql-connect

Comment: I seriously just did. It probably couldn't have been done 'more' for you. Just create a php file dump this in it and above all this make sure you connect to the mysql database that the wordpress is attached too.

Comment: i am no pro with PHP and appreciate it

Comment: i updated the code above if you can please let me know what im doing wrong